# Create Dynamic Menu for HTML Website

Tags: javascript, html, menu

I am trying to find out how I can create a dynamic menu on my site that will display text and link to articles that I add to a certain directory.

For example, if I had a subdirectory title 'Articles', how can I add the contents of this folder in my menu?

If you have an alternative method, I would be grateful if you can share that.

Thank you

Comment: are u using any json which contains the article title and links because if you are having that you can create a DOM with the title and links in your page

Comment: Thanks. No not using json - would that be simple to implement?

Comment: yes it is easy to implement when you are retrieving the titles and links from server to html if you get it in json format you can easily do that